# Exclusion feature in keycloak IDM

Tags: wildfly-10, keycloak, identity-management, identitymanager

I am trying to develop an web application using angular 4, java ee and wildfly. I am planning on using keycloak as IDM. I researched and found that we can provide roles to `user` but what I couldn't find is if it provides the feature to exclude some privilege from `admin` role.

For example: I want to provide user with  `admin` role all the privileges except one, so I want to exclude the privilege from that `admin`.

Is it possible using keycloak? If not, can anyone suggest any other IDM matching this requirement?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the documentation: http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/topics/roles.html ?

Comment: I had a look at the documentation. What I want is even for the role admin, I don't want to give all privileges to all admin. I want some restrictions on some admin role

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change the privileges of *admin* role. Yes, you can use Keycloak.
From http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/topics/admin-console-permissions/fine-grain.html

> Fine grain permissions are used to grant additional permissions. You cannot override the default behavior of the built in admin roles.

I think you still can achieve want you want with Keycloak's flexible administrative role and permission management. Just not exactly in the way  you think it should be done.
Don't give your *administration user* the role *admin*, but some of the more restrictive roles of client **realm-management** (e.g. *view-realm*, *manage-users*).